# React Native Expo - Localization

Tags: react-native, localization, google-play, expo, location-services

Im using expo-localization. When I try to submit the app to the google play store, it says that the app uses location service. Is there a way for the app not to use the location service as Im only getting the timezone form it. The timezone is used to get an approximation of where the user base is.

Is there a way for expo to not use the location service or what should I write in the permission declaration.

this is the warning from the play store

Your background location permission declaration needs to be updated.

This release includes permissions that haven't been declared in Play Console. Go to Sensitive        app permissions to update your permission declarations.

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';

let tz = Localization.timezone;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the permissions requested to empty in the app.json file.

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.myco.myapp",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "permissions" : []
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Expo set permissions by default, just put this in your app.json

```
"permissions" : []
```

Answer (score -1):

Same problem in **Xamarin**.

Your background location permission declaration needs to be updated.

var locationStatus= await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
if (locationStatus!= PermissionStatus.Granted)
locationStatus= await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();